# Responsive Image That Stretches to Full Size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to force images that are generated for a splash page to stretch to full size but at the same time have the image be responsive and fluid.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="newsImage">
                <xen:contentcheck>
                <xen:if is="{$news.attach}">
                    <a href="{xen:link threads, $news}"><img src="{xen:link attachments, $news.attach}" alt="{$news.attach.filename}" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;" /></a>
                <xen:elseif is="{$news.image}" />
                    <a href="{xen:link threads, $news}"><img src="{$news.image}" alt="{$news.image}" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;" /></a>
                <xen:else />
                    <xen:avatar user="$news" size="m" itemprop="photo" />
                </xen:if>
                </xen:contentcheck>
                        <div class='newsTitle'><h2><a href="{xen:link threads, $news}" title="{$news.title}">{xen:helper threadPrefix, $news}{$news.title}</a></h2></div>

            </div>
```

Here is the CSS

I'm sure the max-width is incorrect in terms of making it responsive but it seems to force the stretching that I want.

```
.recentNews .newsImage        { width:100%; height:auto;  }
.recentNews .newsImage img        { max-width:100%; height:auto;  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So whats the problem? You could also just use width:100%; for the image and it will grow and shrink because your parent is 100%

Comment: I tried that Shan but then the images were too big and not conforming to size.

Comment: hmmm, display block on the parent maybe? More styles effecting the image? Your example (or even slightly similar) ways is how I always achieve that effect. But doesn't it work with your code?

Answer (score 5):

Background size property:

```
background-size: cover;
background-size: 100% 100%\9; /* IE8 */
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason why you are setting the width and height with inline styles? It should work if you remove them.

<strike>`style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"`</strike>

---

`max-width` will work if the image is larger than the div, else you'd want to set the `width` to `100%` so smaller images can stretch to the width of the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/WPxnG/2/

#### HTML

```
<div class="recentNews">
    <div class="newsImage">
        <a href="#"><img src="//lorempixel.com/1500/1500/" alt=""/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.recentNews .newsImage img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
}
```